# System Settings are broken, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: crash, unity-control-center

When I run System Settings, I see a dialog box:

Sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error.

If you notice further problems, try restarting the computer.

I tried:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt remove unity-control-center
sudo apt install unity-control-center
```

to no avail.

Somewhere in the end of the crash log at /var/crash I see

```
SegvAnalysis:
 Segfault happened at: 0x7ffb68337549:  mov    (%rsi),%rsi
 PC (0x7ffb68337549) ok
 source "(%rsi)" (0x00000000) not located in a known VMA region (needed readable region)!
 destination "%rsi" ok
SegvReason: reading NULL VMA
SourcePackage: unity-control-center
Stacktrace:
 #0  0x00007ffb68337549 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl20.so.20
 No symbol table info available.
 #1  0x00007ffb6833f838 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.20
 No symbol table info available.
 #2  0x00007ffb6837cf42 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.20
 No symbol table info available.
 #3  0x00007ffb68336401 in cogl_renderer_connect () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.20
 No symbol table info available.
 #4  0x00007ffb6862a9ef in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-1.0.so.0
 No symbol table info available.
 #5  0x00007ffb68643523 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-1.0.so.0
 No symbol table info available.
 #6  0x00007ffb68654979 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-1.0.so.0
 No symbol table info available.
 #7  0x00007ffb68654b80 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-1.0.so.0
 No symbol table info available.
 #8  0x00007ffb9753ff67 in g_option_context_parse () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
 No symbol table info available.
 #9  0x00007ffb68655928 in clutter_init () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-1.0.so.0
 No symbol table info available.
 #10 0x00007ffb699c94fc in cheese_gtk_init () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcheese-gtk.so.25
 No symbol table info available.
 #11 0x00007ffb6a314e33 in g_io_module_load () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/unity-control-center-1/panels/libuser-accounts.so
 No symbol table info available.
 #12 0x00007ffb97aaff36 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
 No symbol table info available.
 #13 0x00007ffb978326a1 in g_type_module_use () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
 No symbol table info available.
 #14 0x00007ffb97ab0315 in g_io_modules_load_all_in_directory_with_scope () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
 No symbol table info available.
 #15 0x000000000040a15a in ?? ()
 No symbol table info available.
 #16 0x00007ffb9782f359 in g_type_create_instance () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
 No symbol table info available.
 #17 0x00007ffb9781131b in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
 No symbol table info available.
 #18 0x00007ffb97812c01 in g_object_newv () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
 No symbol table info available.
 #19 0x00007ffb97813534 in g_object_new () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
 No symbol table info available.
 #20 0x0000000000407493 in main ()
 No symbol table info available.
StacktraceAddressSignature: /usr/bin/unity-control-center:11:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.20.4.1+31549:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.20.4.1+39838:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.20.4.1+76f42:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.20.4.1+30401:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-1.0.so.0.2400.2+6b9ef:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-1.0.so.0.2400.2+84523:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-1.0.so.0.2400.2+95979:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-1.0.so.0.2400.2+95b80:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.2+54f67:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-1.0.so.0.2400.2+96928:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcheese-gtk.so.25.0.3+74fc:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/unity-control-center-1/panels/libuser-accounts.so+24e33:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.4800.2+60f36:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.2+366a1:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.4800.2+61315
StacktraceTop:
 ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.20
 ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.20
 ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.20
 cogl_renderer_connect () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.20
 ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-1.0.so.0
Tags:  xenial
ThreadStacktrace:
 .
 Thread 5 (Thread 0x7ffb8caee700 (LWP 21744)):
 #0  0x00007ffb96fff70d in poll () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
 No locals.
```

but it's not very informative I guess.

Comment: Perhaps reinstall libcogl20? `sudo apt install --reinstall libcogl20` as the segfault happens there.

Comment: Useful suggestion. I've chosen to dump Unity and switch to Gnome so I probably won't be able to check it.